# Bitbucket Pipeline unable to copy file Error: COPY failed: no source files were specified

Tags: docker, vue.js, bitbucket

I'm trying to set up bitbucket pipline to automate build stage
but I got **error** and pipline failed

```
COPY ./fronted/package*.json ./
COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

### But when I build in my host machine

`root@project:/frontend# docker build -f docker/Dockerfile -t frontend:6.0 .`

**build successful**
Anyh idea?

File structure in bitbucket

```
|-- fronted
|   |-- package.json
|   |-- other frontend files
    |-- docker
|       |-- Dockerfile
|       |-- nginx.conf
|-- bitbucket-pipelines.yml
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Step 2: Create Nginx Server
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

`bitbucket-pipline.yml`

```
image: atlassian/default-image:3

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:          
    - step:
        runs-on: 
          - 'self.hosted'
          - 'linux'
        name: Build and Save image
        script:
          - echo "Building Docker image"
          - export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
          - docker login docker-c2.comp.net -u admin -p $NEXUS_PASSWORD
          - docker build -f frontend/docker/Dockerfile -t docker-c2.comp.net/support-center-netcore/fronted-support-center-netcore-kz:v1.$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER .
          # Push the Docker image to the container registry2
          - docker push docker-c2.comp.net/support-center-netcore/fronted-support-center-netcore-kz:v1.$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

It's due to working directory.

In your host, you are building under **frontend** folder, where docker is able to **COPY** package*.json.

In bamboo server, you are building in the parent folder of **frontend**, where  package*.json doesn't exist, thus docker throws an error.

To fix it, you need to add **cd frontend** step in bamboo job.